# How to inform C# code when executable created using PyInstaller exits?

Tags: c#, python, windows, process

Similar questions are answered for linux, but I couldn't find for windows.
I have a Python script as follows:

```
import sys
import os

#do something

# sys.exit(0) used this one, as well
os._exit(0)
```

which I convert to windows executable using PyInstaller.
And the C# code is:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(path, "Long Argument");
process.Exited += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Process Finished"); }; ;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The process starts and runs correctly. But when it exits `Exited` event is not raised.
I am also not sure in which side I am doing it wrong, C# or python.

Comment: do you actually have a Exited Event..? [Process.Exited Event MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan Your answer is correct. Solved. EnableRaisingEvents should have been true. You can post it as answer and I accept it. Maybe someone else does the same mistake like me.

Comment: glad that I was able to quickly help you out..feel free to accept when you get a chance

Comment: @MethodMan I did=) and I was as fast as you but I saw your comment late.

Comment: not a problem @ozgur glad that I could help you out .. have a great day.. cheers..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an event for Process.Exited explained here [Process.Exited Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx)

based on this coded portion of the example you are missing `EnableRaisingEvents` should be set to `true`

```
private Process myProcess = new Process();
private int elapsedTime;
private bool eventHandled;

// Print a file with any known extension.
public void PrintDoc(string fileName)
{

    elapsedTime = 0;
    eventHandled = false;

    try
    {
        // Start a process to print a file and raise an event when done.
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
        myProcess.Start();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred trying to print \"{0}\":" + "\n" + ex.Message, fileName);
        return;
    }

    // Wait for Exited event, but not more than 30 seconds.
    const int SLEEP_AMOUNT = 100;
    while (!eventHandled)
    {
        elapsedTime += SLEEP_AMOUNT;
        if (elapsedTime > 30000)
        {
            break;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AMOUNT);
    }
}
```